# Integration of $\int x^2\sqrt{K^2-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no ideas about how to handle this integral. Here $K$ is a parameter. I tried using integration by parts ($\int u \cdot dv$) putting $u=x\sqrt{K^2-x^2}$ and $dv=x\cdot dx$, but I'm not able to come up with any useful solution...

Comment: Why is the integral improper?

Comment: @0inegue what about trigo substitution. Have you tried?

Comment: The problem asks $\int_{0}^{K}$, but my issue was in evaluating the improper integral first

Comment: @juniven what do you mean? Sorry but I'm still a newbie with this kind of exercises :)

Comment: @0inegue The answer of Oloa is much easier than the one I suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x=K\cos(t)$ with $t\in[0,\pi]$, then $\sqrt{K^2-x^2}=|K|\sin(t)$. the integral becomes

$$-\int K^3|K|\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)dt$$

$$=-\frac{K^3|K|}{4}\int \frac{1-\cos(4t)}{2}dt$$

$$=-\frac{|K|K^3}{8}(t-\frac{\sin(4t)}{4}).$$

with $t=\arccos(\frac{x}{K})$.
result=

$$-\frac{|K|K^3}{8}\arccos(\frac{x}{K})+\frac{x(2x^2-K^2)}{16}\sqrt{K^2-x^2}+C$$